# Rails belongs to association method undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi i'm having a problem with a rails association. I have the Table Users and the table Roles. Here are my migrations:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.belongs_to :role, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :code

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Im having the problem when I create a user with a role that I had previously created

`Role.create(name: 'Super Admin', code: 'super_admin')`

`User.create(email: 'a@b.com', password: 'abcdefg', role_id: 1)`

When I try to do User.first.role I get that the method role is undefined. As far as i know When i do that i should get an active record with the role.

What i am doing wrong. Please Help

Comment: Your migrations are only part of the puzzle. Can you post your User and Role models as well please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the relation to your model. In user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :role

   # other code
end
```

It will generate the ActiveRecord methods you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah thank you just after i post this i realize that i was missing that